# Are polynomials/quadratic equations linear equations or linear combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, terminology

I have a really basic question about what constitutes a "linear equation". In "Linear Algebra and Its Applications",

$$x_{2} = 2x_1^{2} + 6$$

is an example of a **non-linear** equation. But in statistics, this would still be considered a linear model.

I'm confused about how a linear equation is defined - does the definition change between linear algebra and statistics?

Comment: It's a matter of context, not subject. $x^3+7x+42$ is nonlinear as a function of $x$, but it's a linear combination of $x^3$, $x$ and $1$.

Comment: Linear models in statistics are linear combinations of predictors.

Comment: "*Does the definition of ___ change between different branches?*"  In many cases, yes.  Just wait till you hear all of the dozens of ways "normal" is used in mathematics with completely different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

A linear equation is of the form $ax=b, a\ne 0$

The exponent of x must be 1.

The reason the equation is called linear is that the side of the equation containing the unknown x is essentially the equation of a line, while the side free of x is the equation of a horizontal line.

Solving a linear equation is equivalent to finding the x-coordinate of the point of intersection of two lines.

The example you gave is not of a linear equation but of a quadratic equation, where the exponent of x is 2 along with terms that may or may not exist where the exponent of x is 1 or zero.

For a polynomial equation to be called a linear equation, the degree of the polynomial must be 1. Otherwise the polynomial equation is nonlinear.

Comment: there was a typo in my question (fixed now). Just to summarize - this is a quadratic equation, not a linear equation but it is a linear combination of terms?

Comment: The equation you wrote in $x_1$ and $x_2$ has two unknown quantities but is not a linear equation because of the square $x_2^2$. Is not a linear combination either. What was called a linear combination in first comment refers to the vector space of polynomials up to third degree.